Find limit of Decrementing Recursive Series
I want to find a formula to find the lower limit part of this recursive or geometric series
$$
x_{n} = \left( x_{n-1} + p \right) \times \left( 1 - \frac{t}{100} \right)
$$
I was just wondering what method I should use to find the lower limit of this equation with a given value of $p$ and $t$ as the value $x_1$ doesn't seem to effect the end state of the formula
When calculating by hand I found that, for example, when using
$$
x_{1}=100\ \ \ \ p=10\ \ \ \ t=20
$$
I find it hits a lower limit of 40
here is what I found when doing some simple tests as what they collapsed  to



p
t
rough collapsed value




10
20
40


11
20
44


12
20
48


10
30
90


10
10
~23.33333


11
10
99



So far I haven't been able to find a formula or equation that charts this out, can anyone help?

This is hard to read.

I've tried fixing the table allowing it to be easier to read, sorry about that

It's a lot better now.

If you assume a limit exists, then you can solve for it by setting $x_{n-1}=x_n=z$. I'm going to use $k= \left( 1 - \frac{t}{100} \right)$ for shorthand: $$
x = \left( x + p \right) \times k \\
x(1-k) = pk \\
x = \frac{pk}{1-k} \\
x = \frac{pk}{\frac{t}{100}}=\frac{100pk}{t}
$$
A lower limit will definitely exist for $0 < t < 200$. For $t=0$, a limit only exists if $p=0$ (in that case, the limit is just $x_1$). For $t \ge 200$ or $t<0$, things are a little complex; if you set $x_1$ to exactly the right value, you can still have a fixed point (or a cycle like 1,-1,1,-1).

Interesting, I didn't expect there to be a point of the value for t in which it wouldn't end in a single value but just go to infinity

If the limit exists, it is found by solving the equation
$$x=(x+p)\left(1-\frac{t}{100}\right)$$
$$x=p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)$$
To prove when this is indeed the limit, note that for $t\neq 0$ (where the recursion obviously diverges if $p\neq 0$ and converges for $p=0$) we can define
$$y_n= \left|x_n-p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)\right|$$
Then the recursion becomes
$$y_n=\left|x_n-p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)\right|=\left|(x_{n-1}+p)\left(1-\frac{t}{100}\right)-p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)\right|$$
$$=\left|\frac{(-100 + t) (-100 p + p t + t x_{n-1})}{100 t}\right|=\left|\frac{t-100}{100}\right|\left| x_{n-1}-p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)\right|$$
$$=\left|\frac{t-100}{100}\right|
 y_{n-1}$$
For $x_n$ to converge, $y_n$ must converge to $0$: ie
$$|t-100|<100 \text{ or } y_{n-1}=0$$
$$0<t<200\text{ or }y_1=0$$
We already talked about what happens at $t=0$ (diverges unless $p=0$). At $t=200$ the recursion becomes
$$x_n=-x_{n-1}-p$$
which diverges unless $x_1=-\frac{p}{2}$ (in this case then $y_1=0$). If $t<0$ or $t>200$ then the sequence diverges unless $y_1=0$: that is
$$x_1=p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)$$
Summarizing:
$$x_n\to p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)\text{ if }t\in (0,200)$$
$$x_n\to x_1\text{ if }t,p\in\{0\}$$
$$x_n\to x_1\text{ if }t\in(-\infty,0)\cup [200,\infty)\text{ and }x_1=p\left(\frac{100}{t}-1\right)$$
$$x_n\text{ diverges otherwise}$$
